# Draw a circle using im4java

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, im4java

I need to draw a circle and save it as an image in a directory. I want to draw the image using im4java. I have tried to create, but there is no IMoperation available in im4java. Any help???

Comment: how does `netbeans` tag relate to this question?

Comment: How about some code you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im4java is a wrapper to execute ImageMagick commands from your java code.

As you want to call a custom command, not implemented in im4java as a standard method, then either extend im4java functionality to call this command (it is opensource) or use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) to call this custom command.

The ImageMagick command to draw a circle is explained here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#circles